# @model, @page etc are not working on my .net core project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03vBn.png)

I have this error on every @page, @model etc
Even from the begginig, i create a new .net core project and its already filled with errors

I have searched everywhere but no one seems to have the same issue with me

Comment: Hi Rez, welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you please share the error message? We can't see what the error is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the file extension? It should be (.cshtml),
are you following same?